# Can't set headers after they are sent. While calling create(data,cb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm new to node and trying to create a model in mongodb. when I call localhost:3000/a. I see request two time in console also getting error Can't set headers after they are sent

```js
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("adminpanel/panel",{});
  });
  app.get('/a',function (req,res,cb) {
    console.log(req.url)
    var User = app.models.test;
    var user = app.models.test();
    user.username = "admin";
    user.type = "hey";
    user.password = "132";
    user.email = "admin@test.com";
    User.create(user,cb);
    res.send("hey");
  });
};
```

Output:

```js
output: 
  /a
  /a
  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express       \lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:551:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:138:14)
    at E:\workspace\orderapp\server\boot\root.js:14:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\workspace\orderapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
```

Comment: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. means you are trying to send the response more than  once. Can you show the code for your 'cb'.

Comment: that what i'm trying to figure it out where i'm sending response second time. Second why above block of code run two time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens when you finish the request and then later try to send more on the same request.  This usually happens when someone makes a mistake in asynchronous handling which goofs up the timing of when things are sent on the request object.

I see two issues with your code.  First, you're trying to call `next()` from a route handler as if you haven't actually finished handling the request.  Second, you're sending `res.send()` before that you call `next()` because `User.create()` is asynchronous and will finish sometime later.

I'd suggest you use this:

```
  app.get('/a',function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.url)
    var User = app.models.test;
    var user = app.models.test();
    user.username = "admin";
    user.type = "hey";
    user.password = "132";
    user.email = "admin@test.com";
    User.create(user,function() {
        res.send("hey");
    });
  });
```